# Android Studio Failed Error

Tags: android

I was making a project on android studio then i updated android studio. Then i am taking this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  W/ziparchive(12136): Unable to open 'C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\Hayvan Bulma\KpeiYakala\app\build\Ä±ntermedÄ±ates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_': No such file or directory
  error: failed to open APK: I/O error.

  Command: C:\Users\b3rk4\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha10-4662957-windows.jar\10ed1b45d0c7be95ae3f093e6e7cf10e\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha10-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          -I\
          C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\Hayvan Bulma\KpeiYakala\app\build\ıntermedıates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\Hayvan Bulma\KpeiYakala\app\build\ıntermedıates\ınstant_run_merged_manıfests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\Hayvan Bulma\KpeiYakala\app\build\ıntermedıates\ınstant_run_maın_apk_resources\debug\instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug\out\main_resources\resources_ap\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          -0\
          apk\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha10-4662957-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 3s
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Getting similar error but on linux.

Comment: Yes i solved. I deleted all files in everywhere. Then installed again java jdk, android studio etc.

Comment: For anyone still searching (on linux) this was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914803/552902

Answer (score -2):

Lol, for me 'rebuild project' under 'build' fixed everything.